# DatePicker value not changing after even changed

Tags: iphone, datepicker, xcode4.2

```
-(IBAction)showDate:(id)sender
{
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 220, 325, 300)];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
datePicker.hidden = NO;
datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
[datePicker setDate:datePicker.date animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
}



- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date animated:(BOOL)animated
{
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *str = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"String is------:%@",str);
[dateBtn setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

i have gone through UIDatePicker Class reference in Apple's Doc.Based on that i have implemented the code as above.there i am getting only current date on button when external method code is written in button action and not changing date if i am change in DatePicker.

if i write code like mention above, i dint get even any title on button.
i think, am made blunder mistake, can anyone tell me where the mistake is and explain me in detail.

Thanks alot for help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with subclassing, which is something you are not doing here (and don't need to).  You need to setup the date picker to call a method of your choosing when the date is changed; something like this:

```
[datePicker addTarget:self
               action:@selector(dateChanged:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

(See [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:)).

And then implement the method:

```
- (void)dateChanged:(UIDatePicker*)datePicker {
    NSLog("Date changed: %@", datePicker.date);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my app is crashing if i change in datePicker with this code.

Comment: @iPhoneNewBie Crashing where?

Comment: at selecting date picker and am getting message in console as " unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7691690"

Comment: @iPhoneNewBie OK you mistyped either `@selector(dateChanged:)` or `- (void)dateChanged:(id)sender`.  I suspect you missed off the `:`...

Comment: Yup. Sorry i got it @trojanfoe. can u please tell me how that date can be converted to string? i need to display that date on button as title or text. please help me.

Comment: @iPhoneNewBie Just search for 'nsdate to string' or something (it's off topic for this question).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
-(void)timepicker:(UIGestureRecognizer *)date{

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,200,0,0);

    myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [myPicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
    [myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:)               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:myPicker];


}
- (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"value: %@",[sender date]);

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

    NSString *date=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sender date]];

    NSLog(@"value1: %@",date);

   }
```